# Save a copy and replace the last six characters (date format) from a list of user selected MXD documents

Tags: arcpy, mxd, text

The following script has the following objectives:
User selected MXD files.  Here I use a multivalue parameter for FILE with a filter for MXD in the tool box settings. 
Changing selected text based on Text Element Name (dynamic text).
Saving the mxd as copy : removes the last six characters (string reference to the date), and replaces these with the current date string (or a user specified input).

As it stands it saves a copy by simply adding a suffix of the date and does not remove the original ".mxd" so I get a file name that looks like "C:\Home\GIS_Projects\HabitatEnvironments_150122.mxd_150219.mxd" (note the 2 ".mxd"s)
If the original mxd was titled "C:\Home\GIS_Projects\HabitatEnvironments_140629.mxd" the new one (same folder-location) should be the same but with the current date "C:\Home\GIS_Projects\HabitatEnvironments_150219.mxd".

```
import arcpy
import os
import time
import datetime
from time import strftime


mxdString = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #toolbox parameter workspace
#prepare for multivalue toolbox parameter
mxdList = mxdString.split(";")
arcpy.AddMessage(mxdList)
#set new text variables
#These are set parameters in text properties "Element name"
NewMapTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
NewProjectTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
CurrentDate = strftime("%y%m%d")
#THis is where it should loop through the ListInMXD and replace the text.
for mxdItem in mxdList:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdItem.strip("'"))
    for titleNew in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "MapTitle"):
        titleNew.text = NewMapTitle
    for projectNew in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "ProjectName"):
        projectNew.text = NewProjectTitle
    #Save a copy of each mxd with current date at the end
    #This is where it bugs.  I need to strip the last six characters and replace them with "CurrentDate".
    mxd.saveACopy(mxdItem + CurrentDate +".mxd")

del mxd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the saveACopy at the end like so:

```
mxd.saveACopy(mxdItem[:-10] + CurrentDate +".mxd")
```

The mxdItem is just a string, so you can slice it or shorten it like normal strings.  [Here's](http://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) some reference for dealing with strings.  The bit I added just clips the last 10 characters from mxdItem (10 characters, not 6, because you need to remove the original ".mxd").